# Inter glassfish Session Bean sharing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi, session-bean

I'm trying to find a way to do that, but I could not find the riiiiight answer googling it. I think I'm close to it but I fell like something is still missing, or I just need some external opinion that this is the best way.

I'd like to access a Session Bean that is running in a remote Glassfish Server. I'm trying to access it from another Glassfish Server. I looked into JNDI External resources but I could not find a tutorial how to configure it in a situation like this.

My question is: Is this the best way to do it ? If so, can somebody shed a light at how to configure it ? Which port, etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an inherent feature of Coherence+GlassFish. Using Oracle GlassFish Server with Coherence, you can share an HTP session (or session attributes) across applications using flexible scope options.  Check out this [PDF](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/coherence/026046.pdf).

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong but that seems a more enterprise solution. What I'm trying to achieve is to access an Session EJB in another Glassfish instance. I know that I can do the lookup programatically, but I as the client is also in a Glassfish container I thought it would provide an easier and managed solution for that. But I'm not sure ... and also not sure how to configure it. Thanks